# CancellationTokenSource sliding expiration

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

How to implement sliding expiration for `CancellationTokenSource` i.e. to be able to reset its timeout interval?

```cs
TaskCompletionSource<T> source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeoutMs);

cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => source.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false);

// do work and eventually call source.TrySetResult()
// what is the right way to prolong CancellationTokenSource timeout?

return source.Task;
```

### Some extra context:

Imagine application sending command and waiting for reply to arrive. Reply may take 0.1 or 10 seconds and may interrupt. If there is no new data for 1 second it is safe to timeout.

So setting fixed timeout exceeding 10 seconds seems a lot, but sling expiration fits perfectly: when new portion of data arrives, reset 1 second interval.

### UPD

Why not to make timer myself. Of course that was my first thought. However looking into `CancellationTokenSource` source code (CTS is build on timer which is sealed and internal) got me thinking there is a reason for that and maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: presumably you'd setup a timer that calls `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` when it fires, and just keep resetting the timer...? you *would not* create the CTS with a timeout - just use the parameterless constructor

Comment: I have added UPD section. Well, it seemed odd to implement exactly the same logic as CTS has + Reset method.

Comment: `TryReset` might be helpful

Comment: @AlexanderSelishchev try it, see how it goes, let us know! (Genuinely)